# SQL query to get highest value and corresponding date from columns in MySQL table

Tags: sql, mysql

I need a SQL query, to get the highest number from columns: 1, 2, 4 and 5, then returns the respective date and the highest value.

I have this database:

tabela:

| date | coluna1 | coluna2 | coluna3 | coluna4 | coluna5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-01 | 1 | 2 | 88 | 9 | 5 |
| 2023-03-02 | 20 | 11 | 85 | 1 | 55 |
| 2023-05-14 | 12 | 31 | 8 | 2 | 12 |
| 2023-01-04 | 14 | 54 | 4 | 45 | 46 |
| 2023-03-15 | 5 | 45 | 55 | 3 | 75 |

Expected result:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| coluna1 | 2023-03-02 | 20 |
| coluna2 | 2023-01-04 | 54 |
| coluna4 | 2023-01-04 | 45 |
| coluna5 | 2023-03-15 | 75 |

Comment: What version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: How will you handle tie-breaks? Newest or oldest? Are you dealing with 100s, 1,000s or 1,000,000s of rows?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x, one option is to *unpivot (convert columns into rows)* the data and then use the `row_number` function to get the row with max value for each column.

```
with t as
(
  select t.date_, u.val, u.colunax,
     row_number() over (partition by u.colunax order by u.val desc) rn
  from tbl t
  cross join lateral (
    select coluna1, 'coluna1' union all
    select coluna2, 'coluna2' union all
    select coluna4, 'coluna4' union all
    select coluna5, 'coluna5'
  ) as u(val, colunax)
)
select date_, colunax, val
from t
where rn = 1
```

And if your version does not have support for [lateral derived tables](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/support-for-lateral-derived-tables-added-to-mysql-8-0-14/), you can use `union all` to unpivot your data.

```
with t as
(
  select date_, coluna1 val, 'coluna1' colunax from tbl union all
  select date_, coluna2, 'coluna2' from tbl union all
  select date_, coluna4, 'coluna4' from tbl union all
  select date_, coluna5, 'coluna5' from tbl
),
t2 as
(
 select date_, val, colunax,
     row_number() over (partition by colunax order by val desc) rn
  from t
)
select date_, colunax, val
from t2
where rn = 1
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/GAqmdHFc)